# Regions sample app broken or Simulator broken

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, cllocationmanager

Basically, I can't get boundary crossing events - locationManager:did[Enter|Exit]Region: - to trigger.

I posted [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388003/testing-location-with-simulator) about testing locations with the simulator but now think I should rephrase the question.

I've looked through the source code and made sure only the standard location services were used, as opposed to significant-change although they were only used when the app went into the backround or was suspended so it shouldn't have been relevant.  I also used regionMonitoringEnabled and regionMonitoringAvailable in order to check that they were indeed available in the simulator (they are).

But still nothing. updateWithEvent is not called and therefore the table/icon badge number is not updated.

I'm going to keep looking but I can't tell if it's has something to do with how the API works (locationManager:did[Enter|Exit]Region:) or if it's a simulator thing (although the simulator shows location updates nicely).

Comment: You could post some code showing how you have your CLLocationManagerDelegate set up. That is where your callback events are going to respond and where you will need to handle them. Could just be a delegate issue or you are running into the 5.1 simulator bug I found (answer below).

Comment: I'm using the sample app called "Regions" from Apple's dev website.  They look A OK (they're in the file called RegionsViewController).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a known bug in the iOS 5.1 Simulator. I have filed radars with Apple to get it fixed, but have basically been ignored. They responded with "does it work in the iOS 6 beta simulator". Which it does.

I got the same issue where it only triggers one location event for region monitoring. In or out, but no more than one.

You can either download the 5.0 Simulator which should still work or download the new iOS 6 beta (if you have access) to test around the region monitoring, then go back to 5.1 for anything else. Sorry I don't have better news.

Comment: Hmm.  I can't get even one event to trigger for region monitoring.

Comment: I suppose I should download the iOS6 beta simulator and try it out.  I was hesitant because you can't submit to the store but there won't be anything to submit if I can't get this working.

Comment: I'm going to call Apple tomorrow.. can you point me to where I can see that this is a known bug?

Comment: There is a radar open, 11715223.

Comment: How do I go about finding that radar number?  I'm going to mention it to apple when I reply to their TSI response.

Comment: All you should have to do is tell them what the radar number is, they can look it up.

Comment: Ah, right.  I was thinking that there was a way to search the bug database.  I just filed one myself (11852260).

Answer (score 0):

Try going to "iOS Simulator" > "Reset Content and Settings".  That's always a good first place to start with simulator trouble shooting issues.  It does the device equivalent of a restore.  This is especially pertinent if you are messing around in the file system of your simulator.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already deleted the app and reinstalled. Also I am getting some response from Debug > Location settings but not regions.